# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql

I dont know why but I get this error 
:

Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

For this code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM player ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT $begin";
                    $arr = array();
                    while($obj = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query($sql))) {
                            //$arr[] = $obj;
                            echo $obj;
                    }
```

Comment: You need something like `echo $obj->columnname`  Or just to see what's inside `var_dump($obj)`

Comment: Won't this run the query on each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Don't use a construct like `mysql_fetch_obj(mysql_query($query))`  especially not inside a `while loop`.  Always store the output resource of the `mysql_query()` call, test its validity, then call a fetch function on the resource variable.

Comment: Actually this would be an infinite loop generating the same (first) row forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `mysql_fetch_object` (which returns an object) and then trying to output it as a string. That won't work.

In your case, you should use a function that is capable of printing the contents of the object. There are many but the most straight-forward ones are [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).  if you're outputting in an HTML context, you might wan to wrap a `<pre>` tag around the output to make it more readable or click "View source" in your browser.

If you're writing your own objects, they can also be "converted" to strings by implementing the [`__toString()` magic method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)

Also, as people have said in the comments, your code will run the query on each pass through the loop. Check out the [documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php) and read the examples.

Note: You might have simplified the example for SO's sake, but make sure to sanitize your variables (e.g. `$begin`) to avoid SQL injections!

Comment: if you know then please reply answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `print_r` or `var_dump` instead of `echo`