# How to pass data to the view in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a contoller which is like this. It has more arrays than listed here :

```
$this->data['password'] = array(
    'name' => 'password',
    'id'   => 'password',
    'type' => 'password'
);
$this->data['password_confirm'] = array(
    'name' => 'password_confirm',
    'id'   => 'password_confirm',
    'type' => 'password'
);
```

this data is passed to the view using phil sturgeon template like this:

```
$this->template
        ->title("Edit your Profile")
        ->set_theme('admin')
        ->set_layout('dashboard')
        ->set_partial('links','partials/links')
        ->set_partial('header','partials/header')
        ->set_partial('menu','partials/menu')
        ->set_partial('footer','partials/footer')
        ->build('auth/edit_user', $this->data);
```

My view file is:

```
Password: (if changing password)<br />
<?php echo form_input($password);?>

Confirm Password: (if changing password)<br />
<?php echo form_input($password_confirm);?>
```

Now when i refresh the page, i get the values in the field but also on the top of the page there is a error message:

```
Message:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

Can anyone tell me whats wrong??
P.S using codeingniter hmvc, phil sturgeon template and ben edmunds ion auth....

Comment: try the accepted answer in this question for debugging: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758185/object-of-class-stdclass-could-not-be-converted-to-string

Comment: that helped quite a bit

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to the following to get around this issue:

`$this->data = (array) $this->data;`

and place it before `$this->template->build()`