# how to solve Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string PHP

Tags: php

I am using php and decode json format to array as following code

```
$sub_cats_ids=array();
$sub_cats_ids=json_decode($_POST['sub_cats']);
```

I want to echo first item in array to test if it works fine as following code

```
echo current($sub_cats_ids);
```

but I get this error message

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

I tried this code also

```
echo $sub_cats_ids[0];
```

but I get the same error message 
how I can solve this issue

Comment: Add the second 'true' setting of `json_decode`.

Comment: print_r($sub_cats_ids) to see structure of array

Comment: @splash58 print_r() print array of content successful

Comment: @IncredibleHat true doesn't work

Comment: You really should show us an example of what is coming in on `$_POST['sub_cats']`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [json\_decode to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164404/json-decode-to-array)

Comment: Just add 2nd parameter of true to json_decode() and you get an array instead of an object.  With that said, learn how to echo out properties of an object.

Comment: @IncredibleHat this is the result of print_r($sub_cats_ids)
 stdClass Object ( [IT] => 5 [NETWORKS] => 6 [WEB] => 7 )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758185/object-of-class-stdclass-could-not-be-converted-to-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is crystal clear, isn't it? The current element in the array is an object, *not* a string. You cannot "echo" an object, but only a string. So php tries to convert the object into a string but fails, since no such conversion is defined for an object of the generic standard class.

You need to use a function to output an object instead of the `echo` command, or you need to to convert that object into a string which you can output:

```
<?php
//...
var_export(current($sub_cats_ids));
```

Or to `echo` the object:

```
<?php
//...
echo var_export(current($sub_cats_ids), true);
```

UPDATE:

Your comment below suggests that unlike what you wrote in the question you do not want to output the object itself, but only a specific property of that object. That means you need to access that property in the object, php cannot somehow magically guess that you want to do that.

Without you posting additional information all I can do here is *guess* what you actually need to do:

```
<?php
//...
$object = current($sub_cats_ids); 
echo $object->IT;
```

Comment: result i got is 
stdClass::__set_state(array( 'IT' => '5', ))
how i can get only 5 as value of IT key

Comment: @MokhtarGhaleb I updated the answer considering your additional question in the comment above...

Comment: Many Thanks for your help you get me the key for solving this problem i had another error in code but after fixing it your solution works